# Android Phonegap ChildBrowser - hiding ChildBrowser

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I was wondering if there was any way to hide the ChildBrowser instead of closing it. I would like the webview in the ChildBrowser to persist instead of having to re-start it every time. Any suggestions on how to do this? I tried using dialog.hide() and dialog.show(), but that didn't seem to work. Any help on this subject would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think it's closing the webview?